# mod_rewrite server.com/directory to new.com/directorynew/directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf

I am moving everything to a new domain. If the old domain's url is http://example.com/article/article_title/date/and/etc, I want it to redirect to another server at http://anotherserver.com/extradir/article/article_title/date/and/etc.

Otherwise, if the first arg of the request path isn't "article" just change the domain name and redirect.

Here's my stab:

```
RewriteRule ^/article/(.*)$ http://anotherserver.com/extradir/article/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anotherserver.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first never matches. The second works fine.

It's on Drupal, and placed just below the RewriteEngine On directive in httpd.conf to avoid the Drupal directives.

This is in httpd.conf NOT .htaccess.

Any ideas on why the top RewriteRule isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why your first rule isn't working, it works for me if I put that in my vhost config. Have you tried using `RedirectMatch`?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/article/(.*)$ http://anotherserver.com/extradir/article/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://anotherserver.com$1
```

Comment: You know, sometimes you need a person to express your frustration. This redirect DOES work. The problem was that I had this redirect code in the incorrect <Directory> directive. So, it WAS working, but not in the docroot of the server. Thanks for testing my mod_rewrite rules on a different server. --Joe